# select distinct results using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

**Situation**

I have list of objects, and the linq query I am currently using is counting every item up twice. That happens because the data is setup that way. Every PO number will have two lines, and I am counting both. I only need to count one.

```
PO Number  Pallets
123          5
123          5
234          8
234          8
345          2
345          2
```

**Linq Query**

```
Pallets = (from o in this.OrdersModel
           where o.Pallets != null
           select double.Parse(o.Pallets))
           .Sum();
```

Assuming each object in the set is an OrderModel, when this query is run it will return 30 (all the rows added up)

**Desired Outcome**

The correct number of pallets would be 15, add up each PO pallets once.

Instead what I would like to happen is a way to select distinct po number, and then add up the pallets. It would be very easy to add this condition in straight SQL, but I have the slightest idea on how to do it in Linq.

**Question**

1. Is there a quick and easy way to do a select distinct po number using Linq?
2. If not, what would be the best way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Do you mean distinct? There is a linq method called Distinct() although I use the lambda form so I'd struggle to advise on your query

Comment: If you have two entries for each PO Number, how do you know which of the two to include in your sum?

Comment: Well, if you want a fast solution: Pallets = Pallets /2;

Comment: @IanNelson There are a few ways, but initially we do not have the data structure in place to need to worry about that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a quick and easy way to do a select distinct

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
Pallets = (from o in this.OrdersModel.GroupBy(o => o.PONumber).Select(g => g.First())
           where o.Pallets != null
           select double.Parse(o.Pallets))
           .Sum();
```

But you should probably try to fix your model so you don't get duplicate records in the first place!

Comment: @D Stanley That is definately the best approach. We have not quite figured that step out yet. But we will need to eventually not populate every record. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Pallets = this.OrdersModel
                .Where(x=>x.Paletts!=null).Distinct()
                .Sum(x=>double.Parse(x.Pallets));
```

As [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is said, you need to implement `IEquatable` interface, so you can define which items are duplicates (thanks to Raphaël for reminding)

Comment: Assuming `IEquatable<OrderModel>` is implemented

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus yes of course, I forgot to mention that

Comment: @wudzik or use [Enumerable.Distinct<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of implement `IEquatable`

Comment: @Grundy yes, it's another valid option, but I prefer implementing IEquatable in such cases :)

Comment: @wudzik this one looks like it selects distinct palletts. I would need distinct po number

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a fast solution: Pallets = Pallets /2
But this is a quck fix , you should use distinct.